# trying to dynamically hide/show divs based on user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several elements with click events. Each elements click event will only show a div, out of all other divs in the same page, to which it has a relation to. However, when I click on the element, the hidden divs which are supposed to appear do not. I can not see what I am doing wrong here.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

        var showMon = $("#monshowtimes");
        var showTue = $("#tueshowtimes");
        var showWed = $("#wedshowtimes");
        var showThu = $("#thurshowtimes");
        var showFri = $("#frishowtimes");
        var showSat = $("#satshowtimes");
        var showSun = $("#sunshowtimes");

        var monTimes = $(".mon-listings");
        var tueTimes = $(".tue-listings");
        var wedTimes = $(".wed-listings");
        var thurTimes = $(".thur-listings");
        var friTimes = $(".fri-listings");
        var satTimes = $(".sat-listings");
        var sunTimes = $(".sun-listings");
    $(showTue).click(function(){
        $(".screening-days li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".movie-timing").each(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass(".tueTimes")){
                $(this).css("display","block");
            } else $(this).css("display","none");
        })

        });


    })
```

```css
.mon-listings, .tue-listings, .wed-listings, .thur-listings, .fri-listings, .sat-listings, .sun-listings {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<section class="showtimes">

<ul class="screening-days">

<li class="active" id="monshowtimes">Monday</li>
<li id="tueshowtimes">Tuesday</li>
<li id="wedshowtimes">Wednesday</li>
<li id="thurshowtimes">Thursday</li>
<li id="frishowtimes">Friday</li>
<li id="satshowtimes">Saturday</li>
<li id="sunshowtimes">Sunday</li>
<li>Coming Soon</li>

</ul>

<span class="filter">

<p>Filter Films</p>

</span>

</section>

</div>

<!-- END OF VIEWING TIMES & DAYS TABS SELECTION / START OF MAIN MOVIE LISTINGS SECTION -->

<div class="container">

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/ferres.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1987)</h1>

<p>High school student Ferris Bueller wants a day off from school and he's developed an incredibly sophisticated plan to pull it off. He talks his friend Cameron into taking his father's prized Ferrari and with his girlfriend Sloane head into Chicago for the day. While they are taking in what the city has to offer school principal Ed Rooney is convinced that Ferris is, not for the first time, playing hooky for the day and is hell bent to catch him out. Ferris has anticipated that, much to Rooney's chagrin.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Matthew Broderick, Alan Ruck, Mia Sara</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>103min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/back-to-the-future.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Back to the Future (1985)</h1>

<p>Marty McFly, a typical American teenager of the Eighties, is accidentally sent back to 1955 in a plutonium-powered DeLorean 'time machine' invented by a slightly mad scientist. During his often hysterical, always amazing trip back in time, Marty must make certain his teenage parents-to-be meet and fall in love - so he can get back to the future.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span> Michael J. Fox, Christopher Lloyd, Lea Thompson</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>116 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:45</li>


</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/first-blood.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>First Blood (1982)</h1>

<p>John Rambo is a disoriented Vietnam Vet. He is hitchhiking from town to town to see friends from the war. A sheriff tries to make him leave town and when he refuses, arrests him for vagrancy. While in jail, a deputy takes delight in abusing him. Rambo escapes showing his old Vietnam fighting skills and takes to the woods as the sheriff and deputies try and find him in his element. Things get out of hand as Colonel Trautman, Rambo's old commander, appears to shed light on the situation.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Sylvester Stallone, Brian Dennehy, Richard Crenna</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>93 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:00</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/breakfast-club.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>The Breakfast Club (1985)</h1>

<p>They were five students with nothing in common, faced with spending a Saturday detention together in their high school library. At 7 a.m., they had nothing to say, but by 4 p.m., they had bared their souls to each other and become good friends. To the outside world they were simply a Brain, an Athlete, a Basket Case, a Princess, and a Criminal, but to each other, they would always be the Breakfast Club.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Emilio Estevez, Judd Nelson, Molly Ringwald</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>97 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/halloween.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Halloween (1979)</h1>

<p>The year is 1963, the night: Halloween. Police are called to 43 Lampkin Ln. only to discover that 15 year old Judith Myers has been stabbed to death, by her 6 year-old brother, Michael. After being institutionalized for 15 years, Myers breaks out on the night before Halloween. No one knows, nor wants to find out, what will happen on October 31st 1978 besides Myers' psychiatrist, Dr. Loomis. He knows Michael is coming back to Haddonfield, but by the time the town realizes it, it'll be too late for many people.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Donald Pleasence, Jamie Lee Curtis, Tony Moran</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>91 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:15</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>12:30</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>15:15</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:15</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>22:30</li

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>12:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>15:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>19:00</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/goodfellas.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Goodfellas (1990)</h1>

<p>Henry Hill might be a small time gangster, who may have taken part in a robbery with Jimmy Conway and Tommy De Vito, two other gangsters who might have set their sights a bit higher. His two partners could kill off everyone else involved in the robbery, and slowly start to think about climbing up through the hierarchy of the Mob. Henry, however, might be badly affected by his partners' success, but will he consider stooping low enough to bring about the downfall of Jimmy and Tommy?</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>146 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>12:25</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:50</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>17:35</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want to show ? What do you want to show ?

Comment: All divs are originally hidden. But when I click on the Tuesday <li> with the id tueshowtimes, for example, I would like the all ul elements with the class "tue-listings" to show, but no the rest. When i click o Monday with the id monshowtimes, I would like all the ul's with the class  mon-listings to show etc.

Comment: Instead of adding styling to the element directly, either toggle a class, like a `.hidden` class or something, or use jQuery [Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). They will be easier to manage.

Comment: And, I think `$(this).hasClass(".tueTimes")` should be `$(this).hasClass("tueTimes")`

Comment: But you don't have that class in css - so it probably should be `$(this).hasClass("tue-listings");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a little with your code…
(I removed all of your JS, created a function that hides all and shows only the timings of the day clicked - at first, I used the `onclick` of each `li` of `.screening-days` in the html, but then I binded it to the "click" event of your `.screening-days li`. I also modified the class `thur-listings` to `thu-listings` to have all the days on 3 letters, just because I prefer.)
… and ended up with this:

```js
$(".screening-days li").click(function(){
  $(".screening-days li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".movie-timing").hide();
  $("." + $(this).attr("id").substr(0, 3) + "-listings").show();
});

// We can even open listings on page load based on current day !
$(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var days = ["sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"];
  $("#" + days[d.getDay()] + "showtimes").trigger("click");
});
```

```css
.movie-timing {
  display: none;
}
.screening-days .active {
  color: blue;
}
.screening-days li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="showtimes">
    <ul class="screening-days">
      <li id="monshowtimes">Monday</li>
      <li id="tueshowtimes">Tuesday</li>
      <li id="wedshowtimes">Wednesday</li>
      <li id="thushowtimes">Thursday</li>
      <li id="frishowtimes">Friday</li>
      <li id="satshowtimes">Saturday</li>
      <li id="sunshowtimes">Sunday</li>
      <li id="comshowtimes">Coming Soon</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="filter">
    <p>Filter Films</p>
    </span>
  </section>
</div>

<!-- END OF VIEWING TIMES & DAYS TABS SELECTION / START OF MAIN MOVIE LISTINGS SECTION -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/ferres.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1987)</h1>
        <p>High school student Ferris Bueller wants a day off from school and he's developed an incredibly sophisticated plan to pull it off. He talks his friend Cameron into taking his father's prized Ferrari and with his girlfriend Sloane head into Chicago
          for the day. While they are taking in what the city has to offer school principal Ed Rooney is convinced that Ferris is, not for the first time, playing hooky for the day and is hell bent to catch him out. Ferris has anticipated that, much to
          Rooney's chagrin.</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Matthew Broderick, Alan Ruck, Mia Sara</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>103min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
        <li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
        <li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/back-to-the-future.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>Back to the Future (1985)</h1>
        <p>Marty McFly, a typical American teenager of the Eighties, is accidentally sent back to 1955 in a plutonium-powered DeLorean 'time machine' invented by a slightly mad scientist. During his often hysterical, always amazing trip back in time, Marty
          must make certain his teenage parents-to-be meet and fall in love - so he can get back to the future.</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span> Michael J. Fox, Christopher Lloyd, Lea Thompson</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>116 min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
        <li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
        <li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/first-blood.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>First Blood (1982)</h1>
        <p>John Rambo is a disoriented Vietnam Vet. He is hitchhiking from town to town to see friends from the war. A sheriff tries to make him leave town and when he refuses, arrests him for vagrancy. While in jail, a deputy takes delight in abusing him.
          Rambo escapes showing his old Vietnam fighting skills and takes to the woods as the sheriff and deputies try and find him in his element. Things get out of hand as Colonel Trautman, Rambo's old commander, appears to shed light on the situation.</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Sylvester Stallone, Brian Dennehy, Richard Crenna</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>93 min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>17:00</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>18:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>22:00</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
        <li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
        <li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/breakfast-club.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>The Breakfast Club (1985)</h1>
        <p>They were five students with nothing in common, faced with spending a Saturday detention together in their high school library. At 7 a.m., they had nothing to say, but by 4 p.m., they had bared their souls to each other and become good friends.
          To the outside world they were simply a Brain, an Athlete, a Basket Case, a Princess, and a Criminal, but to each other, they would always be the Breakfast Club.</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Emilio Estevez, Judd Nelson, Molly Ringwald</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>97 min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
        <li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
        <li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/halloween.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>Halloween (1979)</h1>
        <p>The year is 1963, the night: Halloween. Police are called to 43 Lampkin Ln. only to discover that 15 year old Judith Myers has been stabbed to death, by her 6 year-old brother, Michael. After being institutionalized for 15 years, Myers breaks
          out on the night before Halloween. No one knows, nor wants to find out, what will happen on October 31st 1978 besides Myers' psychiatrist, Dr. Loomis. He knows Michael is coming back to Haddonfield, but by the time the town realizes it, it'll
          be too late for many people.</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Donald Pleasence, Jamie Lee Curtis, Tony Moran</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>91 min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>13:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>15:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>18:15</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>17:00</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>12:30</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>13:30</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>15:15</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:15</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>17:00</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
        <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
          <li>SATURDAY<br>14:45</li>
          <li>SATURDAY<br>16:30</li>
          <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
          <li>SATURDAY<br>20:35</li>
          <li>SATURDAY<br>21:15</li>
          <li>SATURDAY<br>22:45</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
          <li>SUNDAY<br>12:30</li>
          <li>SUNDAY<br>13:30</li>
          <li>SUNDAY<br>15:15</li>
          <li>SUNDAY<br>16:15</li>
          <li>SUNDAY<br>19:00</li>
          <li>SUNDAY<br>22:30</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="classic-movie">
    <div class="movie-summary">
      <div class="movie-image">
        <img src="images/movie-images/goodfellas.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">
      </div>
      <div class="movie-name-plot">
        <h1>Goodfellas (1990)</h1>
        <p>Henry Hill might be a small time gangster, who may have taken part in a robbery with Jimmy Conway and Tommy De Vito, two other gangsters who might have set their sights a bit higher. His two partners could kill off everyone else involved in the
          robbery, and slowly start to think about climbing up through the hierarchy of the Mob. Henry, however, might be badly affected by his partners' success, but will he consider stooping low enough to bring about the downfall of Jimmy and Tommy?</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci</p>
        <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>146 min</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-showtimes">
      <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">
        <li>MONDAY<br>12:25</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>14:50</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>17:35</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">
        <li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
        <li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing thu-listings">
        <li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">
        <li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
        <li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">
        <li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
        <li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">
        <li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
        <li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that the way you wanted to achieve that?

Anyway, I hope it will be helpfull.

Edit: I added the current day listings opening on page load, because I thought it was cool.

Comment: I forgot about `.hide()` and `.show()` - way better than my suggestion. I kind of miss JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two issues currently in code. For generic solution, check the others answers.

1. `$(this).hasClass(".tueTimes")` class should not need `.` when you check with hasClass.
2. I didn't see any class called `tueTimes`. I think this should changed to `tue-listings`.

If you make the above two changes that will fix your issue.

```js
var showMon = $("#monshowtimes");
  var showTue = $("#tueshowtimes");
  var showWed = $("#wedshowtimes");
  var showThu = $("#thurshowtimes");
  var showFri = $("#frishowtimes");
  var showSat = $("#satshowtimes");
  var showSun = $("#sunshowtimes");

  var monTimes = $(".mon-listings");
  var tueTimes = $(".tue-listings");
  var wedTimes = $(".wed-listings");
  var thurTimes = $(".thur-listings");
  var friTimes = $(".fri-listings");
  var satTimes = $(".sat-listings");
  var sunTimes = $(".sun-listings");
  $(showTue).click(function() {
    $(".screening-days li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    
    $(".movie-timing").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("tue-listings")) {
        $(this).css("display", "block");
      } else $(this).css("display", "none");
    })

  });
```

```css
.mon-listings, .tue-listings, .wed-listings, .thur-listings, .fri-listings, .sat-listings, .sun-listings {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<section class="showtimes">

<ul class="screening-days">

<li class="active" id="monshowtimes">Monday</li>
<li id="tueshowtimes">Tuesday</li>
<li id="wedshowtimes">Wednesday</li>
<li id="thurshowtimes">Thursday</li>
<li id="frishowtimes">Friday</li>
<li id="satshowtimes">Saturday</li>
<li id="sunshowtimes">Sunday</li>
<li>Coming Soon</li>

</ul>

<span class="filter">

<p>Filter Films</p>

</span>

</section>

</div>

<!-- END OF VIEWING TIMES & DAYS TABS SELECTION / START OF MAIN MOVIE LISTINGS SECTION -->

<div class="container">

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/ferres.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1987)</h1>

<p>High school student Ferris Bueller wants a day off from school and he's developed an incredibly sophisticated plan to pull it off. He talks his friend Cameron into taking his father's prized Ferrari and with his girlfriend Sloane head into Chicago for the day. While they are taking in what the city has to offer school principal Ed Rooney is convinced that Ferris is, not for the first time, playing hooky for the day and is hell bent to catch him out. Ferris has anticipated that, much to Rooney's chagrin.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Matthew Broderick, Alan Ruck, Mia Sara</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>103min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/back-to-the-future.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Back to the Future (1985)</h1>

<p>Marty McFly, a typical American teenager of the Eighties, is accidentally sent back to 1955 in a plutonium-powered DeLorean 'time machine' invented by a slightly mad scientist. During his often hysterical, always amazing trip back in time, Marty must make certain his teenage parents-to-be meet and fall in love - so he can get back to the future.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span> Michael J. Fox, Christopher Lloyd, Lea Thompson</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>116 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:45</li>


</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/first-blood.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>First Blood (1982)</h1>

<p>John Rambo is a disoriented Vietnam Vet. He is hitchhiking from town to town to see friends from the war. A sheriff tries to make him leave town and when he refuses, arrests him for vagrancy. While in jail, a deputy takes delight in abusing him. Rambo escapes showing his old Vietnam fighting skills and takes to the woods as the sheriff and deputies try and find him in his element. Things get out of hand as Colonel Trautman, Rambo's old commander, appears to shed light on the situation.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Sylvester Stallone, Brian Dennehy, Richard Crenna</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>93 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:00</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/breakfast-club.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>The Breakfast Club (1985)</h1>

<p>They were five students with nothing in common, faced with spending a Saturday detention together in their high school library. At 7 a.m., they had nothing to say, but by 4 p.m., they had bared their souls to each other and become good friends. To the outside world they were simply a Brain, an Athlete, a Basket Case, a Princess, and a Criminal, but to each other, they would always be the Breakfast Club.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Emilio Estevez, Judd Nelson, Molly Ringwald</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>97 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/halloween.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Halloween (1979)</h1>

<p>The year is 1963, the night: Halloween. Police are called to 43 Lampkin Ln. only to discover that 15 year old Judith Myers has been stabbed to death, by her 6 year-old brother, Michael. After being institutionalized for 15 years, Myers breaks out on the night before Halloween. No one knows, nor wants to find out, what will happen on October 31st 1978 besides Myers' psychiatrist, Dr. Loomis. He knows Michael is coming back to Haddonfield, but by the time the town realizes it, it'll be too late for many people.</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Donald Pleasence, Jamie Lee Curtis, Tony Moran</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>91 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>18:15</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>12:30</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>15:15</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:15</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>17:00</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>22:30</li

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>12:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>15:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>19:00</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

<div class="movie-summary">

<div class="movie-image">

<img src="images/movie-images/goodfellas.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

</div>

<div class="movie-name-plot">

<h1>Goodfellas (1990)</h1>

<p>Henry Hill might be a small time gangster, who may have taken part in a robbery with Jimmy Conway and Tommy De Vito, two other gangsters who might have set their sights a bit higher. His two partners could kill off everyone else involved in the robbery, and slowly start to think about climbing up through the hierarchy of the Mob. Henry, however, might be badly affected by his partners' success, but will he consider stooping low enough to bring about the downfall of Jimmy and Tommy?</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci</p>

<p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>146 min</p>

</div>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

<ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

<li>MONDAY<br>12:25</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>14:50</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>17:35</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing tue-listings">

<li>TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
<li>TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing wed-listings">

<li>WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing thur-listings">

<li>THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing fri-listings">

<li>FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
<li>FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sat-listings">

<li>SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
<li>SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

</ul>

<ul class="movie-timing sun-listings">

<li>SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
<li>SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</ul>


</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `regurgitating what I suggested in a comment`. How could you say that? When i started typing answer i will not read all the people comment what they are saying and do you think the snippet i created after reading your comments? `And your snippet doesn't actually answer the question` - OP asked the question why he didn't able to the section. that's it. He is not asking like why other days click is not working. OP wants know whats wrong on his code. Thats it.

Comment: @adpro If someone mentioned suggestion in their comment, do you think no one should the same kind of code in their answer. If it is a solution everyone will use it. I didn't understand how you can give downvote for this reason?

Comment: But your given answer no need to give the solution for all his mind reading.

Comment: I just given what is wrong in his current code. Now i mentioned in my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you check for the wrong class in your JS script. This should be the correct line I think:

`if ($(this).hasClass("tue-listings"))`

- You do not need the `.` here
- and use `tue-listings` instead of `tueTimes`

Answer (score 0):

Give each .screening-days list item a data-class of the unordered list it is related to and use this js code instead. This could alternatively be done with the checkbox hack which would be more efficient (give it a google), but as the question is about show/hide with jQuery, here you go.

**HTML**

```
<li class="active" data-class="mon-listings" id="monshowtimes">Monday</li>
<li id="tueshowtimes" data-class="tue-listings">Tuesday</li>
<li id="wedshowtimes" data-class="wed-listings">Wednesday</li>
<li id="thurshowtimes" data-class="thur-listings">Thursday</li>
<li id="frishowtimes" data-class="fri-listings">Friday</li>
<li id="satshowtimes" data-class="sat-listings">Saturday</li>
<li id="sunshowtimes" data-class="sun-listings">Sunday</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.movie-timing {
    display:none;
}
.movie-timing.show {
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.screening-days li').click(function(){
   $('.screening-days li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');

   var dataClass = $(this).data('class');
   $( '.movie-timing' ).removeClass('show');
   $( '.movie-timing.'+dataClass ).addClass('show');
});
```